# Creating Missing Rows Based on Conditions

Tags: sql, netezza

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the two following tables:

```
# table_a
id  year
1   2010
1   2011
1   2012
1   2013
1   2014
2   2010
2   2011
2   2012
2   2013
2   2014
3   2010
3   2011
3   2012
3   2013
3   2014

# table_b

id  year    var1
1   2010    A
1   2014    B
2   2012    A
2   2013    C
3   2010    A
3   2011    Z
```

**My Question:** I am trying to write SQL code to accomplish the following task:

- Step 1: For a given ID in table_b, take the earliest available year : I want to add new rows for this id until 2014. For example, ID = 1 would have rows added for 2011, 2012, 2013. Id = 2 would have rows added only for 2014. ID = 3 would have rows added for 2012, 2013, 2014
- Step 2: Anytime a new row is added, the value of var1 is assigned the text 'not available'
- However, the only exception to Step 2: If a given ID has var1 = Z, then for all new rows that are added, var1 will be assigned a value of 'Z'.

**The final answer would look something like this:**

```
id  year    var1
1   2010    A
1   2011    not available
1   2012    not available
1   2013    not available
1   2014    B
2   2012    A
2   2013    C
2   2014    not available
3   2010    A
3   2011    Z
3   2012    Z
3   2013    Z
3   2014    Z
```

Here is what I tried so far:

**Part 1:** I understand that I need to first create the missing rows - I thinks can be done like this:

```
select 
g.id,
h.year 
from
(select id, 
min(year) as start 
from table_b
group by id)g
join table_a h on
h.id 
between g.start and 2014)
```

**But from here, I am not sure how to proceed.
Can someone please show me how to continue working on this problem?**

Note: Ideally, I would like to solve this problem with a set of basic CTEs as recursive functions are not available within Netezza.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perform a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.year,
COALESCE(b.var1, c.var1, 'not available') AS var1
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b ON b.var1 != 'z' AND a.id = b.id AND a.year = b.year
LEFT JOIN table_b AS c ON c.var1 = 'z' AND a.id = c.id
```

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=joins-left-outer-joinleft-join

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-coalesce

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! but how will your code fill the missing "var1" values according to the criteria? i.e. "not available" or "z"

Comment: The value will be NULL. Is that not enough? If so then use COALESCE(b.var1, 'not available')

Comment: thank you so much for this update! all added values for id = 3 should have var1 = z ... but when I run your code, I am getting var_1 = "not available". Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Updated with an added condition. I don't have a sql instance to double check the correct syntax but play around with it a bit. Shouldn't be too far off from this

Comment: I think there might be a small error here ... I am getting an error "Duplicate alias "b" in query!" ... I will try to see where this is coming from....